# Moving Files In Google Drive Using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create documents using information posted through Google forms, then once the document is created I would like to move the document into a shared folder for people to view.

At the moment I have the script taking all of the information from the Google Forms linked spreadsheet.

Using that information I'm using the following code to create the document:

```
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(TARGET_FOLDER_ID);
  var newDoc = DocumentApp.create(requestID + " - " + requestSummary);
```

This is creating the document successfully in my Google Drive root folder, but I can't seem to move it where I want to move it to.

I've seen a lot of posts suggesting use stuff like targetFolder.addFile(newDoc) but that doesn't work, similarly I've seen examples like newDoc.addToFolder(targetFolder) but again this isn't working for me.

It seems that all the online questions people have already asked about this are using the previous API versions that are no longer applicable and these methods do not apply to the new DriveApp functionality.

What I would like, if possible, is to create the new document as above so that I can edit the contents using the script, then be able to move that file to a shared folder. (From what I understand there is no 'move' function at present, so making a copy and deleting the old one will suffice).

Answer (score 41):

If we make a copy of the file and trash the original, it would change the file URL and also the file sharing settings won't be preserved.

In Drive, it is possible to [add a file to multiple folders](http://www.labnol.org/internet/add-files-multiple-drive-folders/28715/) with the `.addFolder()` method of `DriveApp` service. You can add the file to the target folder and then remove the file from the immediate parent folder.

```
function moveFiles(sourceFileId, targetFolderId) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFileId);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId);
  file.moveTo(folder);
}
```

Comment: Probably safer to store a reference to the original folder, add the file to the new one, and _then_ remove it from the old one. That way if adding it to the new one failed, it's still in the old folder.

Comment: Also note that if you're moving the files from My Drive in to Team Drive, you don't need to call `removeFile`. Simply calling `addFile` causes the file to be removed from My Drive. Probably because the [ownership changes](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/123584/207).

Comment: The .addFile method is currently deprecated and does not work anymore. Use File.moveTo() as mentioned in other answers.

Comment: The .addFolder() method you mention is also deprecated. Sorry for being a pain :D

Answer (score 16):

This is my first post! I know this has been answered a few times, but I actually came across this question while working on my project, and while reviewing the Apps Script documentation, I figured out a concise way to do it. A variation of some1's answer.

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileid);
DriveApp.getFolderById(folderid).addFile(file);
DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like there is now a [moveTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#moveTo(Folder)) function with the Drive API (advanced services) that makes it easy to move files:

> **moveTo(destination)**
>
> Moves this item to the provided destination folder.
>
> The current user must be the owner of the file or have at least edit
> access to the item's current parent folder in order to move the item
> to the destination folder.

Here is some code I used to move all files from the "screenshot input" folder to the "screenshot processed" folder:

```
var inputFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(SCREENSHOT_INPUT_FOLDER_ID);
var processedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(SCREENSHOT_PROCESSED_FOLDER_ID);

var files = inputFolder.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.moveTo(processedFolder);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct method in the [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) or [Folder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder) Classes to move files from one folder in Google Drive to another. As you mentioned you can copy the file to another folder with the method [makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#makecopyname-destination) and then delete it with [setTrashed()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#settrashedtrashed), the code should look like this:

```
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(TARGET_FOLDER_ID);
  var newDoc = DocumentApp.create(requestID + " - " + requestSummary); // Creates the Document in the user's Drive root folder

  // Modify the new document here, example:
  // var body = newDoc.getBody();
  // body.appendParagraph("A paragraph.");
  // newDoc.saveAndClose();

  var driveFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newDoc.getId()); // Gets the drive File

  driveFile.makeCopy(newDoc.getName(), targetFolder); // Create a copy of the newDoc in the shared folder
  driveFile.setTrashed(true);  //  sets the file in the trash of the user's Drive
```

**EDIT:**

In a second thought and taking into account Ruben's comments. I agree that it is a better practice to implement Amit's answer.

Comment: Thanks @Rubén (: I think both answers are right in the context of the user's needs. @Amit is right about changing `id` and `sharing settings`, that is important when you want to move files from one folder to another and they have already been shared to some users.. In this case @S Woodhouse wants to create the file, modify it and then move it, I think he doesn't care about the `id` and `sharing settings` of the "temporary file.

Comment: Personally I would use another approach, by using the Advanced Drive Service to create the final document and inserting it in directly in the target folder. with `Drive.Files.insert(file)` , but that is for the user to decide (:

Comment: We could say that both posts answers the question but I think that adding/removing a file from folders is a better practice to move a file than creating a copy file and deleting the original one. Actually, the second is more related to the main content (data) than the file itself (data and metadata).

Comment: I totally agree on that ;) Also on I'm not sure but maybe creating a copy of the file will impact on the daily quota, that will be another disadvantage of this approach. I edited my answer so it adds value to the OP or future readers (:

Answer (score 3):

Use [File.moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#moveTo(Folder)).

```
var newFileId = newDoc.getId();
var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newFileId);
newFile.moveTo(targetFolder);
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit safer approach compared to the previous ones:

1. If you remove link to the file first, then you will not be able to addFile.
2. If file is already located in the target folder, then the approach provided by Amit (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810986/11912486) only removes file.

So, I suggest to use the following approach:

```
function move_file(file_id, target_folder_id) {
  var source_file = DriveApp.getFileById(file_id);
  var source_folder = source_file.getParents().next();
  if (source_folder.getId() != target_folder_id) {
    DriveApp.getFolderById(target_folder_id).addFile(source_file);
    source_folder.removeFile(source_file);
  }
}
```

can be improved by:

- javascript camel style
- multiple locations validation

Answer (score 1):

The script transfers all your personal files to a **shared disk** (Team drive). **Saves the folder structure.**

```
DRIVE_FOLDER_ID = '111aaa'; // Folder ID on the shared drive

function start() {
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"me" in owners');
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      newPath = fileMoveWithPath(file, DRIVE_FOLDER_ID);
      
      console.info("New path: ", getFullPath(newPath));
    }
}

function fileMoveWithPath(file, root) {
  var folders = [],
      parent = file.getParents();

  // Проходим по иерархии папок текущего файла до корня
  while (parent.hasNext()) {
    parent = parent.next();
    folders.push(parent);
    parent = parent.getParents();
  }

  console.info("Old path: ", getFullPath(file));
  if (folders.length > 0)
    targetPath = makeNewPath(folders, DriveApp.getFolderById(root));
  else
    targetPath = DriveApp.getFolderById(root);

  if (targetPath) {
    targetFile = file.moveTo(targetPath);
    return targetFile;
  };
  return;
}

function makeNewPath(folders, newroot) {
  var f = folders.pop();
  var query = "'" + newroot.getId() + "' in parents and title = '" + f.getName() + "' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' "
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.searchFolders(query);
  if (targetFolder.hasNext()) 
    targetFolder = targetFolder.next()
  else
    targetFolder = newroot.createFolder(f.getName());

  if (folders.length > 0) 
    return makeNewPath(folders, targetFolder)
  else
    return targetFolder;
}

function getFullPath(file) {
  var folders = [],
      parent = file.getParents();
  while (parent.hasNext()) {
    parent = parent.next();
    folders.push(parent.getName());
    parent = parent.getParents();
  }
  if (folders.length) {
    return '> /' + folders.reverse().join("/") + '/' + file.getName();
  }
  return '> /' + file.getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newDoc.getId());
targetFolder.addFile(file);
//DriveApp.getFolderById('root').removeFile(file); // remove from root
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered, but here is a slightly different configuration:

```
function moveFile(parameterObject) {
  var currentFolderID,file,fileToMoveID,sourceFolder,targetFolder,targetFolderID;

  fileToMoveID = parameterObject.fileToMoveID;
  currentFolderID = parameterObject.currentFolderID;
  targetFolderID = parameterObject.targetFolderID;

  file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileToMoveID);//Get the file to move

  if (!file) {
    functionToHandleThisKindOfThing("there is no file");
    return;
  }

  if (currentFolderID) {//The folder ID holding the current file was passed in
    sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(currentFolderID);
  } else {//No ID for the current folder
    sourceFolder = file.getParents();
    if (sourceFolder) {
      if (sourceFolder.hasNext()) {
        sourceFolder = sourceFolder.next();
      }
    }
  }

  targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderID);

  targetFolder.addFile(file);
  sourceFolder.removeFile(file);
}

function testCode() {
  var o;

  o = {
    'fileToMoveID':"File ID of file to Move",
    "targetFolderID":"ID of folder to Move to"
  }

  moveFile(o);

}
```