# How to move all files of a specific type between Google Drive folders

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was delighted to find Amit Agarwal's script in [Moving Files In Google Drive Using Google Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808875/moving-files-in-google-drive-using-google-script/38810986#38810986), that allows one to move a file from one folder to another on Google Drive.

```
function moveFiles(sourceFileId, targetFolderId) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceFileId);
  DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId).addFile(file);
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
}
```

How could this be modified to select only files of a specific type, say PDFs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the MIME type of the file and then move the matching files. Here's a modified version of the [original snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38810986/512127).

```
function moveFiles(source, target) {
  var sourceFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(source);
  var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(target)
  var files = sourceFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    targetFolder.addFile(file);  
    file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Amit, exactly what we need. You've saved me (and I think many others) a great deal manual moving of files. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Brian If you feel the code solved the issue, you may accept the answer.

Comment: I apologize, Amit, for my delay. I wanted to do some additional testing. I also have a folder which contains several sub-folders, each which contains 2 pdf's. Can your script move all the pdf's in the sub-folders if I use the root folder as the sourceID? Thanks very much.

Comment: Rather than `"application/pdf"`, I recommend using the built-in enum [`MimeType`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type), because it supports auto-completion in the editor, reducing the possibility of a typo breaking your code. `var files = sourceFolder.getFilesByType(MimeType.PDF);`