# Move all root folder files into folder without creating copies

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to move all files inside the root of Google Drive into a specified folder such as shown below without creating copies of the to be copied files?

[image]

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `efficient` you are thinking, if `efficient` is the process cost, how about using [Drive API with the batch request](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch)? By this, the process cost can be reduced. If `efficient` is the number of use of APIs, how about using [Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive)? By this, you can move the files without using API quotas. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: If you are still looking for the solution, can I ask you about your current issue?

Comment: I prefer to have my root folder clean and want to periodically move all files into a folder to not clutter up root. However, some of those files are shared, so I can't delete them and create a copy. Need to move without deleting files.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I think that the existing answer can resolve your issue. For example, if there are a lot of files in the root folder, I recommend to use Drive API and the batch request. But I cannot understand about your situation. So I had asked about it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
function myFunction() {
  var files = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderIDGoesHere').addFile(file);
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(file);
    Logger.log(file.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, looks like there's a similar answer already available here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46135473/10713297 

Comment: Thanks! If I understand correctly, this is removing the files in the root folder and is creating copies inside the specified folder?

Comment: Thanks but looking for a solution without creating copies.

Comment: @orschiro - I'm curious :) Were you able to find something that did not leave copies?